# Can HTTP 304 message be avoided?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When using Codeigniter or a simple php page, loadin my test page once I get the normal 200 status but if it is cached I get the 304 message. I realize this is just a signal that the resource is cached but could I avoid it?
If so, how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... or you could just do

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

in your PHP files right at the top. That way you have control over which pages not to cache and leave Apache running as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the page to be cached by browsers you need to configure the apache server to send the appropriate headers.

Comment: I think if you want to get the browser to skip the request you need to ensure "public" is set on cache-control, as well as give it a "max-age". e.g. cache-control:public, max-age=3600